# Shader Graph Unity 2019 как программно установить разные значения параметра шейдера у нескольких объектов?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, shader-graph

- Сделал шейдер с параметром в Unity 2019 Shader Graph.
- Сделал префаб с материалом из этого шейдера.
- Создал несколько объектов из префаба.
- Теперь хочу присвоить разным объектам разное значение параметра шейдера.

Как это сделать? В редакторе Unity параметр меняется у материала и действует сразу на все объекты.

Comment: Нужно создать **разные** материалы

Comment: То есть материал - это как экземпляр настроек шейдера? Набор его параметров?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я это сделал программно, с помощью MaterialPropertyBlock примерно так:

```
Rendererz = GetComponent<Renderer>();
Rendererz.sharedMaterial = myMaterial;
materialPropertyblock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
materialPropertyblock.SetColor("_BaseColor", new Color(0, 0.2f, 0));
Rendererz.SetPropertyBlock(materialPropertyblock);
```